# Deploy JavaFx+Spring Boot+JPA+MySQL application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, javafx, spring-data-jpa, desktop-application

I'm new Java developer and I'm developing a stock management desktop application with JavaFx and Spring Boot.
The application is supposed to allow multiuser connection. This meant, the same application will be installed on many client desktops (in a LAN).
All client will use the same MySQL or SQL server database.

I thought about a solution, but don't know how to implement it:
- Installing the application will generate a custom config file which will contain the database and hostname url so that we can modify it with the hostname, username and password... etc.

Please help me.

Comment: Spring boot has extensive support for [external application configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config). You can specify default settings within the application itself; a more user-friendly approach is perhaps on startup, if the connection fails, prompt the user in the UI to edit the settings and save them to a configuration page (which will be read on next startup), then refresh the application context. Your question really is too broad though; try something and ask a specific question if it fails

Comment: Thanks. I will try your approach. I think it could work.